# Textbox1.Focus(); does not work; as does not Page.SetFocus(Textbox1); why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus, setfocus

as stated both of these do not work (from `Page_Load`):

```
Textbox1.Focus();
```

or

```
Page.SetFocus(Textbox1);
```

any idea why?

this is the control itself:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="Textbox1"
                runat="server" MaxLength="80"></asp:TextBox>
```

it is located on a page, two master pages deep. the form tag is on the second master page, so that is why the focus is not being set there.

not working in: ie, firefox, chrome and safari (all latest versions).

help!
thnx

edit: **need any more info?** i'll do / post anything just tell me what to do to help you help me, i tried EVERYTHING. even google is out of results and is showing my this question.

Comment: What is the context here, UpdatePanel, standard full load?  Also, are you sure you have no javascript errors happening?

Comment: just a page load, no fancy stuff. it is just a web form (ajax not included).

Comment: calling Textbox1.Focus(); and Page.SetFocus(Textbox1); from Page_Load.

Comment: SetFocus and Focus are going to require some JavaScript (not AJAX). Can you confirm there are no JS errors.

Comment: well there probably IS some problem. not sure if it is JavaScript. i see no error...

Comment: i am not using any javascript on my own, there is just the javascript that gets inserted automatically (by the likes of Textbox1.Focus();
and Page.SetFocus(Textbox1);).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, here is what the ACTUAL problem seems to be.

```
<asp:Content ID="PlaceHolder1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolder1"
    runat="server">
```

i have no idea how those ID's (ID="PlaceHolder1") got there, but they seem to be the problem.

i figured it out by remaking the project from scratch and seeing if the focus method works in there, then (among other things, so I could post here) i found out this difference.

this works:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
```

hope this helps someone, sometime...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
<form id="Form1" defaultfocus="Textbox1" runat="server">
```

Or since you mentioned a page in within a MasterPage so it will be in a ContentPlaceholder:

```
    ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder) Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    cp.FindControl("Textbox1").Focus();
```

Make sure you reference your Master in your aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MyMaster.master" %>
```

Comment: i tried it. not working. error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. here's what i did: i put <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MyMaster.master" %> on the page (not master page) and ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder) Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); cp.FindControl("Textbox1").Focus(); on the master page (tried it also on the page (not master page)). not working. not even sure WHY i'd need to do something like this?!?

Comment: thnx for trying, i figured out what the problem was (see my own answer).

Comment: That will not work for an asp:form control as defaultFocus is not a property of ASP

Answer (score 0):

you can write the js code control the textbox  in the client event window.onload=.....

Answer (score 0):

if your page use the master page , you should find the the textbox firstly ,so then set the textbox focus. and you also should attention the events sequence of the page and master

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, sorry.